# How do I build lsqlite3 for lua.5.3.1

Tags: sqlite, lua, cl

I am looking to build lsqlite3 0.9.4 for lua 5.3.1 on Windows 10.
However I am not entirely sure how to go about it.
There is a rockspec file but I am not sure if I should be trying to do it through that(because by default I think luarocks is configured for 5.1) or manually with Visual Studio Developer console.
I unfortunately do not have much knowledge on what I should be doing.
From my guess googling/trial and error here is what I have done, and I have no idea if this is correct so forgive me.

```
cl /nologo /MD /O2 -c -Folsqlite3.obj -I"C:/Lua/5.3.1/include" lsqlite3.c -Dluaopen_lsqlite3=luaopen_lsqlite3complete
```

(Basically got this command from luarocks when it failed to work)
And then I did this:

```
LINK.EXE /DLL /OUT:lsqlite3.dll lsqlite3.obj
```

Which gave me a bunch of unresolved external sqlite3 symbol errors which I kind of expected, I just am not sure where to include in sqlite3..

Any advice on how to properly do this?

Answer (score 0):

First. It ships with sqilte sourece itself.
But luarocks has 2 modules. One require separate SQLite library.
And one build sqlite and lsqlite in single file. So it has no external deps.
Also I think lsqlite3 has bug on Windwos. It provide access to `sqlite3_temp_directory`. But this not defined on Windows where host application should define it. So lsqlite just try use ifdef to ignore this. But it test `WIN32` macro which not defined on MS compiler. So you have 2 ways.
1. Edit rockspec/make file and define `WIN32`
2. Edit source and use `_WIN32` instead

This is output from LuaRocks make command

```
d:\tmp\lsqlite3_fsl09x>luarocks make lsqlite3-0.9.4-0.rockspec
cl /nologo /MD /O2 -c -Folsqlite3.obj -Ic:\luarocks\x86\5.1\include\ lsqlite3.c -DLSQLITE_VERSION="0.9.4" -Dluaopen_lsqlite3=luaopen_lsqlite3complete lsqlite3.c
cl /nologo /MD /O2 -c -Fosqlite3.obj -Ic:\luarocks\x86\5.1\include\ sqlite3.c -DLSQLITE_VERSION="0.9.4" -Dluaopen_lsqlite3=luaopen_lsqlite3complete sqlite3.c
link -dll -def:lsqlite3complete.def -out:lsqlite3complete.dll c:\luarocks\x86\5.1\lib\lua51.lib lsqlite3.obj sqlite3.obj
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

   Creating library lsqlite3complete.lib and object lsqlite3complete.exp
cl /nologo /MD /O2 -c -Folsqlite3.obj -Ic:\luarocks\x86\5.1\include\ lsqlite3.c -DLSQLITE_VERSION="0.9.4" -Ic:/luarocks/x86/external/include
lsqlite3.c
link -dll -def:lsqlite3.def -out:lsqlite3.dll c:\luarocks\x86\5.1\lib\/lua51.lib lsqlite3.obj -libpath:c:/luarocks/x86/external/lib sqlite3.lib
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

   Creating library lsqlite3.lib and object lsqlite3.exp
lsqlite3 0.9.4-0 is now installed in c:\luarocks\x86\5.1\systree (license: MIT/X11)
```

But if you have no separate SQLite libray you just can remove one module form rockspec and use only one (and also rename module).

```
build = {
    type = "builtin",
    modules = {
        lsqlite3 = {
            sources = { "lsqlite3.c", "sqlite3.c" },
            defines = {'LSQLITE_VERSION="0.9.4"'}
        }
    },
    copy_directories = { 'doc', 'examples' }
}
```

This is output for LuaRocks make command

```
d:\tmp\lsqlite3_fsl09x>luarocks make lsqlite3-0.9.4-0.rockspec
cl /nologo /MD /O2 -c -Folsqlite3.obj -Ic:\luarocks\x86\5.1\include\ lsqlite3.c -DLSQLITE_VERSION="0.9.4" lsqlite3.c
cl /nologo /MD /O2 -c -Fosqlite3.obj -Ic:\luarocks\x86\5.1\include\ sqlite3.c -DLSQLITE_VERSION="0.9.4" sqlite3.c
link -dll -def:lsqlite3.def -out:lsqlite3.dll c:\luarocks\x86\5.1\lib\/lua51.lib lsqlite3.obj sqlite3.obj
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

   Creating library lsqlite3.lib and object lsqlite3.exp
lsqlite3 0.9.4-0 is now installed in c:\luarocks\x86\5.1\systree (license: MIT/X11)
```

Comment: Well I managed to do this manually going through the commands because luarocks kept trying to use lua5.1.dll instead of lua51.lib.
Now I need to see if it works with lua 5.3.1, because my build didn't build a .lib file, and am not 100% sure how to do that.

Comment: You can try my https://github.com/moteus/lua-windows-environment setup which has prebuild sqlite library. Also Lua-Sqlite3 installs on windows without problem.